# Trying to get Resource ID dynamicly

Tags: android, resources, imageview

I'm trying to fill `imageViews` dynamicaly with this code:

```
inventorySpace[i].setImageResource((getResourceId(testimg, "mipmap", getPackageName())));

public int getResourceId(String pVariableName, String pResourcename, String pPackageName) {
    try {
        return getResources().getIdentifier(pVariableName, pResourcename, pPackageName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
}
```

However, it does not work. If I use resource name, it works fine:

```
inventorySpace[i].setImageResource(R.mipmap.testimg);
```

I don't think that error is on `getResourceId()` because it works fine with my TextViews like below:

```
public void initInventory()
{
    String name = "item0";

    for(int i = 1; i < inventorySize; i++)
    {
        inventoryViews[i] = findViewById(getResourceId(name+i, "id", getPackageName()));
        inventorySpace[i] = (ImageView)(inventoryViews[i].findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem));
        itemDescriptions[i] = (TextView)(inventoryViews[i].findViewById(R.id.itemDesc));
    }
}
```

Could you please help me to find why it fails only while setting image resource.

Comment: Could you please share how you defined testimg String? Also, put some log and check what getResourceId() is returning for testimg. Share the results of your debug tests

Comment: testimg was beign filled in a method but with a wrong value, thanks for setting me on the right track it works now